# Split rows and divide corresponding value equally

Tags: spotfire

I would like to split certain group name in a column into two different group name and divide their corresponding value equally.

Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

which I would like to split into 2 rows with different group name, and the row value divided equally:

[image]

The original table has a lot more rows and columns but it's only a selected few product group that I would like to divide them equally.

Any idea how I can do this in Spotfire?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a lookup table to join to in order to know that product A can decompose into B and C? What if it was product C? Would it decompose into A and B or D and E? Is there an ID column to link these two (B and C) records to the parent A record? Spotfire is not and should not be your ETL tool. This feels like a significant transformation of data and should be done in an ETL tool.

Comment: I've tried adding a calculated column for B and C, which works fine on its own, but the problem arise when I want to add all the products in the same cross table, so instead of Product A, I want to compare B, C and also other products like D,E,F in the same cross table with their corresponding value. It's only product A which I'm required to divide them equally to B and C. B & C are new names which are not in the original data source

Comment: @DLWEB The question was about if there is a table that says Product A is broken down into products B and C, Product D into E, F and G, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by writing a TERR data function (Edit>Data Function Properties>Register New), but it will require you to know the R language. You will need to pass the initial data table into the function, loop through the rows and write new rows using the logic you have. This will give you a new data table you can output back into Spotfire.

```
outputDataTable <- inputDataTable[0,]

for(i in 1:nrow(inputDataTable)) {

  product <- inputDataTable[i,1]
  sales <- inputDataTable[i,2]
  newRow1 <- data.frame(Product=paste(product,1, sep="_"), Sales=sales/2)
  newRow2 <- data.frame(Product=paste(product,2, sep="_"), Sales=sales/2)
  outputDataTable <- rbind(outputDataTable, newRow1, newRow2)
}
```